# How do I send a proper request to browserstack in nightwatch.js custom command?

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I've done a ton of research on this ([browserstack docs](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/nightwatch), [this older example](https://github.com/blueimp/nightwatch-browserstack), and [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to name a few) yet my code is still not working. I also reached out to browserstack, so I'm pending help from them. First I set the session ID:

```
    module.exports.command = function (browser, done) {
        browser.session(function (session) {
        browser.browserStackSessionId = session.sessionId;
        console.log("browser.bsSessionID: "+ browser.browserStackSessionId);
        done();
      });
```

Then, I make the request:

```
 var request = require("request");
 console.log("making request");
    request({
        uri: `https://${BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME}:${BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${browser.browserStackSessionId}.json`,
        method:"PUT",
        form:{"status":"failed","reason": JSON.stringify(browser.currentTest.results.failure)}},
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log("Error " + error);
            console.log("Response " + JSON.stringify(response.statusCode));
            })
```

When the code runs, the console logs appear in terminal. The session ID is what I expect. I incorrectly set the auth at first so I was receiving error responses which tells me that the code is running, but I'm not seeing updates in my browserstack dashboard so maybe the data isn't sending.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to mark a test session as failed. Could you please try executing a sample NodeJS script:

```
var request = require("request");
request({uri: "https://your_browserstack_username:your_browserstack_access_key@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/<session-id>.json", method:"PUT", form:{"status":"passed","reason":""}})
```

The same details are available in the link: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#rest-api